Azure DevOps Container Agent Exits After Pipeline Completes — How to Keep It Idle?
Question:
I am using Azure DevOps with a container agent, and I want the agent to remain idle and continuously running even after a build pipeline completes. However, the agent container is exiting as soon as the pipeline finishes.
I added the following command to the end of my Dockerfile to keep the container running:
CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"] 
Here is my complete Dockerfile:
Dockerfile

`# Base image
RUN apk update && apk upgrade

# Installing OpenJDK 11, Node.js, and other required packages
RUN apk add --no-cache bash curl git icu-libs jq openjdk17-jre nodejs npm

ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk
ENV PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"

# Verify Java and Node.js installations
RUN java -version && node -v && npm -v

WORKDIR /azp/

COPY ./start.sh ./
RUN chmod +x ./start.sh

RUN adduser -D agent
RUN chown agent ./
USER agent

# Another option is to run the agent as root.
# ENV AGENT_ALLOW_RUNASROOT="true"

ENTRYPOINT [ "./start.sh" ]
CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
`


Despite this, the agent container still exits after the pipeline completes. I’ve tried running the container in detached mode, using the tail command, and interactive mode, but none of these methods have worked.
What am I missing? How can I ensure that the container agent remains idle and does not exit after the pipeline has finished?

How do you interact with the agent?  "The container exits when its entrypoint completes" is normal behavior; why do you want to keep the container, and what would you do with it?  (This particular CMD setup passes tail, -f, and /dev/null as command-line arguments to the start.sh script, which is apparently ignoring them.)

Please clarify "the agent container still exits after the pipeline completes".  How did you create the container and run the self-hosted agent in it? Did you follow the official doc Run a self-hosted agent in Docker and use the start.sh in this official doc?

Hi @user25518631, try to add -d parameter to docker run, then the container will keep running in the background. The agent will stay online and process jobs as they come. See my answer below for the details.

Following the official doc Run a self-hosted agent in Docker, the agent works without any issue. Share the steps below for your reference.

Follow the steps from 1 to 5 in Create and build the Dockerfile and use the azp-agent-linux.dockerfile and start.sh in it.

Build an image using docker build --tag "azp-agent:linux" --file "./azp-agent-linux.dockerfile" .

Run a container with an -d option. The container will run in detached mode and keep running in the background. The agent will stay online and process jobs as they come.
docker run -d -e AZP_URL="<Azure DevOps instance>" -e AZP_TOKEN="<Personal Access Token>" -e AZP_POOL="<Agent Pool Name>" -e AZP_AGENT_NAME="Docker Agent - Linux" --name "azp-agent-linux" azp-agent:linux

Trigger some builds and check the log via docker logs azp-agent-linux

The agent returns to Idle after processing the jobs.



